# No simulator folder in xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, directory, simulator

I am using OSX Yosemite. I have installed xcode 6.1.1 recently but i can't run my code in simulator.

When i press "run" button. It shows error statement which is
"Xcode cannot run using the selected device. No supported iOS devices are available. Connect an iOS device to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination"

I have tried the possible solution. I enter "Devices" page(Windows -> Devices). There is no simulator in the page. Then i click "+" to create simulator. It shows error statement which is "unable to determine SimDeviceSet, set_path=/Users/User Name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices

I can't find this location in my computer. Even i have uninstalled and reinstalled the xcode. The location and related simulator file still can't be found.

Do you guys have any ideas about it? Many thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and re-setting the developer directory made it work again for me (restart Xcode afterwards).

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```